# Sort Collection object by property in Java

Tags: java, list, sorting, arraylist, collections

If I want to sort the Collection below by a property called Order on the CSVInputHandler class, how do I do that? I tried the one a the very bottom with no luck.  The error says `The method sort(List<T>, Comparator<? super T>) in the type Collections is not applicable for the arguments (Collection<CSVInputHandler>, Comparator<CSVInputHandler>)`.

**Object**

```
Collection<CSVInputHandler> csvInputHandlers = new ArrayList<>(csvInputHandlerMap.values());
```

**Tried**

```
  Comparator<CSVInputHandler> comparator = new Comparator<CSVInputHandler>() {
                    public int compare(CSVInputHandler c1, CSVInputHandler c2) {
                        return c1.Order < c2.Order;
                    }
                };

                Collections.sort(csvInputHandlers, comparator);
```

Comment: What is the type of `Order`? You're returning 0 from your `compare()` method which is pointless

Comment: Collections.sort requires a List not an array. I suggest you to read the docs and read the compile errors you are getting.

Comment: I am just using 0 as a test to get the syntax error to go away.

Comment: I know that, but how do you SORT a collection.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Sort ArrayList of custom Objects by property](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2784514/sort-arraylist-of-custom-objects-by-property)

Comment: You get rid of `.toArray()`, since that is changing your List into an array.

Comment: Not a duplicate, I want to sort a COLLECTION!

Comment: Removing .toArray() still causes an error.

Comment: @MikeFlynn not by using Collections... You have to convert your Collection to a List.

Comment: Ok how do I do that????

Comment: @MikeFlynn Come on. Does it make sense to you to sort a Collection? An HashSet is a Collection. Does it make sense to you to sort an HashSet?

Comment: I dont care how I can get it sorted, convert to something else, I just want an answer where I can sort it and iterate over the sorted values.  Lets just say I cant change the object type of Collection, answer the question.

Comment: Collection are not ordered in Java because they contains Set for example, so there is no way to order a collection ;)

Comment: `Collections.sort(new ArrayList<String>(csvInputHandlers ), comparator)`

Comment: Just do `List<CSVInputHandler> csvInputHandlers = new ArrayList<>(csvInputHandlerMap.values());` instead.

Comment: @MikeFlynn Just to tell you. Go read the doc first, check the method signature, try to understand the compile error you are getting. When you are doing Collection<CSVInputHandler> csvInputHandlers, the type is Collection even if the real reference type behind is List. This is really a fundamental concept if you got it then you're fine.

Comment: Is Order object an ENUM?

Comment: @user2336315 I know that, reading the docs wont tell me the correct way to get a collection to a list.  Read the answer below.

Comment: @MikeFlynn The doc clearly states that sort takes a LIST as parameter and you are giving it a COLLECTION (even if the real implementation behind is an ArrayList). So yes reading the docs would have give you the answer. And there are already a dozen of answers on google. Anyway if you don't get it that's not my problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In order to sort a Collection (by using `Collections.sort`) you must explicitly convert it into a List

```
List<CSVInputHandler> myList = new ArrayList<>(csvInputHandlers);

Collections.sort(myList, comparator);
```

Comment: Thank you for actually answering the question

Comment: It's useless, you need to store the reference of the list somewhere. Otherwise it's a no-op.

Comment: @user2336315 good catch... taking out the reference and fixed the parameter type

Answer (score 0):

Remove .toArray() as that sort method accept only List types not Array

```
Collections.sort(csvInputHandlers, comparator);
```

Def

```
public static <T> void sort(List<T> list, Comparator<? super T> c) {
```

Comment: But the type is a Collection not a List :/

Answer (score 0):

The `Collections#sort` method acts on `Collections` so the first method argument must be a `Collection` (i.e. any concrete subtype such as `List`, `Set`) while you are trying to as an array  element as a first argument. It should be

```java
Collections.sort(csvInputHandlers, comparator)
```

Answer (score 0):

Collection :

> The root interface in the collection hierarchy. A collection represents a group of objects, known as its elements. Some collections allow duplicate elements and others do not. **Some are ordered and others unordered**

source http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Collection.html